# Loading less files

Tags: html, less

I started learning less css. Is there any possibility to import different less files

based on view port meta tag. I want to write my own less files for different resolutions.

I also want to know "How does the viewport meta tag works? "

I want to know from the meta tag

how the device width is set to "width" property of the meta tag and the corresponding media

query getting executed.

Comment: http://lesscss.org/#-importing

Comment: can we import the corresponding less files within the media queries?

Comment: Sorry, I thought there were two questions here. Here's info about the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). You'll likely have to do this in JS.

Comment: can you update a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do this with viewport metatag. You can use media queries for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

When compiling Less client site (see: http://lesscss.org/#usage) you could do for example this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 767px)" href="green.less" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 768px)" href="red.less" />
    <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<p>color this text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

with:
green.less: `p{color:green;}` and
red.less: `p{color:red;}` and

Also read http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/12/29/think-twice-before-using-matchmedia-to-conditionally-load-stylesheets/

In most cases you don't use client side compiling for production. Even preprocessors should be used only during the development process. In the production environment the real resulting CSS code should be used. When install LESS on the server, via npm, a compiler for server side compiling will be installed too.

Instead of using media queries to load different resources you could use them inside your less files. For the example above your less code should look like:

```
p{color:green;}
@media(min-width: 768px)
{
    p{color:red;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding media queries to `<link>` element it won't prevent the browser from downloading that css file.

The css file with the media query will be downloaded but it might not be a critical resource and it might not render blocking.

`Finally, note that "render blocking" only refers to whether the browser has to hold the initial rendering of the page on that resource. In either case, the browser still downloads the CSS asset, albeit with a lower priority for non-blocking resources.`

More details https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css